# SIP reply status code and reason null in failure_route

Tags: sip, kamailio

I'm trying to debug why I get `null null` when logging the value of `$rs $rr` using the following kamailio configuration.

Inside request_route:

```
if (is_method("REGISTER")) {
    t_on_reply("REGISTER_FROM_USER");
    # In case of a failure, do a failover:
    t_on_failure("FAILURE_TO_REGISTRAR");
}
```

Inside the failure_route:

```
failure_route[FAILURE_TO_REGISTRAR] {
  xlog("L_INFO","Registrar replied (failure): $rs $rr\n");
```

This outputs:

```
Registrar replied (failure): <null> <null>
```

Comment: Maybe try $rs and $rr outside the "" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `failure_route` the SIP request (e.g., `REGISTER`, `INVITE`) of the transaction is under processing, not the SIP response that triggered the execution of the **failure_route**. This is identified in the core documentation on failure_route [here](https://www.kamailio.org/wiki/cookbooks/5.1.x/core#failure_route) as so:

> Note that in 'failure_route' is processed the request that initiated the transaction, not the reply .

If the message under processing is a response, `$rs` and `$rr` return the response code and reason text. In this case, the message under processing is the request, so these variables both return `null`.

To get the response code and reason text in a `failure_route`, use the transaction variables `T(reply_code)` and `T(reply_reason)` as described [here](https://www.kamailio.org/wiki/cookbooks/5.1.x/pseudovariables#t_name)